# Pandas не читает csv и txt файлы

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Пытаюсь загрузить датасет из файла.

```
wine = pd.read_csv("http://80.78.240.26:8888/edit/wine/Wine.txt", sep='\t', header=None)
wine.head()
```

В итоге выводит эти строчки вместо информации из файла.

```
0   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
1   <html>
2   <head>
3   <meta charset="utf-8">
4   <title>Jupyter Notebook</title>
```

Comment: `DOCTYPE HTML` как бы намекает что это __не__ CSV и __не__ TXT файл...

Comment: Но ведь ссылка на Wine.txt. Как такое может быть?

Comment: скачайте `Wine.txt` на диск и откройте его текстовым редактором, например Notepad++ - сами все увидете...

Comment: @GuyWithMustache когда я открываю вашу ссылку в браузере, то он перенаправляет меня на страницу логина. Возможно, эту же страницу вы получаете, когда пытаетесь считать файл с помощью `read_csv()`?

Comment: @Andrey, скорее всего. Так как этот текст выводится при чтении любого файла. Наверное из-за того что я пользуюсь арендованным виртуальным сервером. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @GuyWithMustache у вас на нём Jupyter запущен и вы оттуда копируете ссылку на файл?

Comment: @Andrey да, в папке /edit код, а в /edit/wine/ датасет

Comment: То есть вы в том же Jupyter на сервере и работаете? Попробуйте может быть так: `wine = pd.read_csv("wine/Wine.txt", sep='\t', header=None)`

Comment: @Andrey, спасибо большое! Теперь работает.